# Allow EC2 to listen to port 443 for unencrypted request from load balancer

Tags: python, ssl, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, wsgi

How can I configure .ebextensions so the EB load balancer terminates https, then forwards the unencrypted request to my EC2 instance. And the EC2 instance reads the request.

My load balancer accepts requests on 2 ports. 80 and 443. 443 has an uploaded cert which I purchased with "AWS Route 53" and requested a certificate with "AWS Certificate Manager" (required to open port 443).

[image]

(*** ssl cert hidden above)

Also my security groups allow https over 443.

The problem is I don't know how to write the `.ebextensions/...config` to allow accepting unencrypted requests over 443 that are passed from the load balancer.

**I found this (amazon docs):**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-python.html
**and (stack overflow):**
[Flask on Elastic Beanstalk with SSL gives 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460019/flask-on-elastic-beanstalk-with-ssl-gives-403-forbidden)

But I think these both give examples when the load balancer is just forwarding the encrypted requests.

I've tried below but it was unsuccessful:

```
#https.config
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupName: {Ref : AWSEBSecurityGroup}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Where I'd like the load balancer to do decryption, then forward the unecrypted request to a port that my app uses.

**In my app:**

```
# wsgi.py
from app import application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=443)
```

Currently `http` works well and fast, but `https` just times out.

I'm a developer but I know almost nothing about sysops.

I've been trying to debug this for over a day so any help would be very appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Based on [Configure apache to listen on port other than 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940909/configure-apache-to-listen-on-port-other-than-80) , I tried changing:

- `Listen 80` to `Listen 443` in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
- `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost *:443>` in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf`
- then ran `sudo /sbin/service httpd restart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve by forwarding both ports as http to my EC2 instance from the load balancer.

Note instance port is `80` and instance protocol is `HTTP` for both.

Previously I was unable to specify `80` for the 2nd because I was leaving the protocol as `HTTPS`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check this.

[AWS - SSL/https on load balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962066/aws-ssl-https-on-load-balancer?rq=1)

And you really should look into not using the built in flask webserver, as its for development only. Try uwsgi or gunicorn

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is only setup Apache to listen on Port 80 and change your load balancer to set the InstancePort to 80 for both incoming ports of 80 & 443.

One of the benefits of SSL termination at the LB is that you don't have to worry about handling multiple ports on the upstream server.

You can use the X-Forwarded-Proto header (which the load balancer provides) in order to determine whether the request originally came in on HTTP or HTTPS so you can build your links/urls etc accordingly.

**EDIT**

An alternative to handling URL creation based on that header is to force https traffic which you can do with something like the below, though I'm an nginx user rather than Apache so your mileage may vary in that the config below might be utter rubbish.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    …
</VirtualHost>
```